# Can someone give me a place to start/hint/topic to review in order for me to answer this problem?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, problem-solving, factoring

I'm not looking for an answer as I would like to do it myself as much as possible, even if it's with help.

The problem:

The number 12 may be factored into three positive integers in exactly eighteen ways,
these factorizations include 1 × 3 × 4, 2 × 2 × 3 and 2 × 3 × 2. Let N be the number
of seconds in a week. In how many ways can N be factored into three positive
integers?

If this is a really easy question I'm going to feel really stupid after this.

Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: Are you familiar with number theory, combinatorics?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  This is all about the fundamental theorem of arithmetic,  that being that every number can be broken down uniquely into a product of primes

So first write down $N$ as a product of primes by breaking down $$7\cdot 24\cdot 60\cdot 60$$
(7 days, 24 hours,  60 hours, 60 seconds),  each into primes.
Now,  you are including permutations in your solutions which can complicate things, but what you are doing is you are splitting the primes into 3 piles (some of which can be empty).  Figure out how many ways there are to do that